# In Spring MVC, what is the correct way to instantiate and persist a new entity?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I want to create and persist an object with member fields which are from other entities. I have the `int` keys of these fields when the user sends this information from a web page.

I see two scenarios for creating the object:

1. Directly make a row in the DB table using those keys but I suspect this is the wrong way to go.
2. Create a constructor which takes objects of the same type as the member fields and invoke the constructor after I obtain the objects using those keys. (I am not sure if this right and if it is, what would be the next step after creating the object. Should I immediately try to persist the new object or not?)

Comment: Spring MVC is a view layer framework an should have nothing to do with the DB layer...

Comment: I was trying to provide background info: explaining why I have keys rather than the objects themselves.

Comment: I think it'll be easier to understand if you add some basic sample code

Comment: This question is more related to JPA/persistence than it is Spring MVC. But if you use JPA, the correct thing to do would be to load (`em.find()`) the objects corresponding to the ids, new the entity in question and assigning the objects fetched to it, before persisting it.

Comment: @Tobb I'm not sure he has to fetch the objects before persisting them. Can't he just create shell objects and assign the foreign ids to them and then persist the root object? Isn't JPA savvy enough to automagically link the objects without having to loading them from the database first? I'll look it up, but its been a while since I've worked with it.

Comment: @Jeff What is your backend configuration? Are you using JPA//Hibernate?

Comment: @Craig I think Hibernate should be able to do this, but not sure if it's part of the JPA spec. Also, it depends a bit on the mappings, which side is the owning side of the relationship etc. The safest is to fetch the objects and assign managed objects to the new one..

Comment: @Tobb that's true, the relationship defined in the database will make this precarious depending on the cascade relationship, where persisting the root entity could possibly persist the foreign shell entity and thereby erase the foreign entity's other fields (not good).

Comment: @Tobb it is part of the JPA spec. EntityManager.getReference() does just that: return a lazy-loaded proxy from an ID, in order to associate another entity with that entity without having to actually load its state.

Comment: OK, now the question has changed, I see the issue. IMO, you should try to load the dependent entities based in the ids the user is sending (use a framework to prevent SQL injection and verify the current user has permissions to assign this members). Later on, you could create your new entity instance, assign the loaded objects and save it.